# What Is The Maximum Value For N In Discrete Logarithm Problems?

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic

I have some code, which can crack a discrete logarithm problem in ~ O(0.5n) time. However, this only works if, in the following, N is less than P:

G^N (mod P). To be clear, my program can figure out the value of N based on G and P as long as N is in between 1 and P (inclusive and exclusive respectively).

This would be helpful for cracking something like Diffie-Hellman, but I have one question: In most discrete logarithm problems like this one, is it common practice to only choose values of N between 1 and P?

Also, I'm not sure if this is the right forum for this kind of thing, please inform me if it is not.

Comment: If a solution exists, there must exist another solution satisfying your constraints, because $G^N \equiv G^{ N \mod{P-1}} \pmod{P}$ (I am assuming $P$ is prime here). In other words, adding or subtracting $P-1$ in the exponent does not change anything.

Comment: How $n$ is related to $N$?

Comment: n is just P - 1, because in my algorithm, the number of steps it takes to complete increases relative to the size of P - 1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of solving for $N$ the equation $G^N\equiv A\pmod P$ for given integers $P$, $G$, $A$ is generally stated for integer $N$ with $0<N\le Q$ for some $Q<P$.

The function $N\mapsto G^N\bmod P$ is periodic. Hence if $N$ is a solution, the set of all solutions is obtained by adding a multiple of the period¹ of that function to that $N$. Thus it's pointless to consider $N$ larger than the period if we can find it, in which case we choose the upper limit for $P$ equal to that period, and name it $Q$. In any case, since $G^N\bmod P$ (when not $0$) belongs to the integers in $[1,P-1]$, which has $P-1$ elements, the period cant exceed $P-1$, hence $Q<P$.

That period $Q$ is the order of $G$ modulo $P$, that is the smallest integer $Q$ with $G^Q\equiv1\pmod P$. It depends on $G$. It is a divisor of $\lambda(P)$, where $\lambda$ is [Carmichael's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). $\lambda(P)$ is $P-1$ when $P$ is prime, lower otherwise.

When the factorization of $P$ is known (including prime $P$), $\lambda(P)$ is easy to compute, and the order of $G$, being a divisor of $\lambda(P)$, also is easy to compute.

Standard practice in cryptography are $P$ a large prime (e.g. at least 1024-bit, that is 309 decimal digits), and $Q$ the order of $G$ modulo $P$, thus $Q$ a divisor of $P-1$. Depending on cryptosystem that can be $Q=P-1$, or prime $Q=(P-1)/2$, or a mildly large prime $Q$ (e.g. at least 160-bit, that is 49 decimal digits)  dividing $P-1$. The former two are common in Diffie-Hellman, the later in Schnorr signature and DSA.

Depending on the magnitude of $P$ and $Q$, the best algorithms we know to find $N$ are either

- [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms), which cost is $\mathcal O(\sqrt Q)$ modular multiplications modulo $P$.
- [index calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm), which cost grows sizably slower when $\log (Q)\lesssim\log(P)$.

---

¹ We define *the* period as the lowest strictly positive period.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot.